# Retrieve from one to many relation. laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to filter my search result. I have been able to retrieve value from many to many table. But i have no idea on how to do that with one to many relationship. 
I have two tables, trips and departures.
A trip has many departures. Their structure are:
Trips:
+++++++++

1. id
2. name
3. other fields..

departures:
++++++++++++

1. id
2. start_date
3. tripsid

Their relations are defined as:
Trip:

```
public function departures()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Departure',"tripsid","id");
    }
```

Departure:

```
public function trips()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Trip','tripsid','id');
    }
```

I want to retrieve those trips who start date = (some year or month(from start_date)).

How can i do this? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence). A couple of examples:

```
Trip::whereHas('departures', function($q) use($date1, $date2) {
    $q->whereBetween('start_sate', [$date1, $date2]);
})
->get();
```

Or:

```
Trip::whereHas('departures', function($q) use($date) {
    $q->where('start_sate', '>', $date);
})
->get();
```